# How I make this select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to get member_id, member_name, member_code and member type matching with part of member name from 2 tables.

My tables structure

> **tutor table**
>   -tutor_id
>   -tutor_name
>   -tutor_code
>
> **institute table**
>   -institute_id
>   -institute_name
>   -institute_code

when I give a part of name from tutor_name or institute_name the query need to recognized this is a tutor or institute. then need to select result.

I tried it something like this. but no luck.

```
SELECT  
    COALESCE(t.tutor_id, i.institute_id) AS member_id,
    COALESCE(t.tutor_name, i.institute_name) AS member_name,
    COALESCE(t.tutor_code, i.institute_code) AS member_code
FROM (tutors AS t OR institutes AS i)
WHERE (t.tutor_name LIKE '%jaya%' OR i.institute_name LIKE '%jaya%');
```

Hope someone pointed me to right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't have `OR` in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: Are any of the columns nullable or will each row returned always be one type or the other?  Is it possible to have results in both tables?

Comment: Yes I need to check both table with given keyword

Comment: if given keyword from tutor_name then need to select member_id, member_name and member_code from tutor table

Comment: if given keyword from institute_name then need to select member_id, member_name and member_code from institute table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is to use UNION:

```
SELECT t.tutor_id member_id, t.tutor_name member_name, t.tutor_code member_code, 'tutor' as type
FROM tutors t
WHERE t.tutor_name LIKE '%jaya%'
UNION 
SELECT t.institute_id, t.institute_name, t.institute_code, 'institute' as type
FROM institute i
WHERE i.institute_name LIKE '%jaya%'
```

However, this might not return what you're looking for.  Without having a common field, there's no way to determine if it's a tutor or an institute...

You might be able to apply a hack like this assuming if a tutor exists, do not show an institute:

```
SELECT t.tutor_id member_id, t.tutor_name member_name, t.tutor_code member_code, 'tutor' as type
FROM tutors t
WHERE t.tutor_name LIKE '%jaya%'
UNION 
SELECT t.institute_id, t.institute_name, t.institute_code, 'institute' as type
FROM institute i
WHERE i.institute_name LIKE '%jaya%' 
   AND 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tutors WHERE tutor_name LIKE '%jaya%')
```

But that seems awfully odd...

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Your query is working. But can I know is there a way to change columns name like member_id, member_name, member_code and member_type;

Comment: @TharangaNuwan -- not sure I'm understanding -- what do you mean?  You cannot change the column names unless you want additional columns. Unions have to have the same column names in both queries.

Comment: yes.. Its working.. but one thing just think given keyword have from tuor_name and institute_name then I need to get result from both table  in same time.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan -- then the UNION query (1st query above) should work fine -- it will return both records.  I added the 2nd query where it would only add the tutor if exists, but as I said, that felt odd.  Good luck.

Comment: can you tell me how change columns name from this line - SELECT t.tutor_id member_id, t.tutor_name member_name, t.tutor_code member_code, 'tutor' as member_type